# <textarea> element is empty after calling jQuery().wrapInner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea and I am trying to wrap the contents with a div.

the HTML

```
<textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="20" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="wprss_ftp_post_prepend" id="wprsspostprepend">Hello World!</textarea>
```

the jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $('#wprsspostprepend').wrapInner("<div id='random-wrap'></div>");
});
```

When I run this code it leaves the textarea blank even if there was content, I am at a loss as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `textarea` can only contain literal text. If you want tags to be allowed inside your editor, use the `pre` element instead:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#wprsspostprepend').wrapInner('<div id="random-wrap"/>')
})
```

```css
.wp-editor-area {
  width: 30em;
  height: 20em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#random-wrap {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre class="wp-editor-area" autocomplete="off" name="wprss_ftp_post_prepend" contenteditable="true" id="wprsspostprepend">Hello World!</pre>
```

Comment: is there any way to do this with a textarea?

Comment: No, sorry; this is the next best option. Anything placed inside a `textarea` is automatically interpreted as text. All rich-text editors have to use `div`, `pre`, and other such tags.